# Self-learning SAT

Tags: reference-request, self-learning

I want to take SAT, but I don't know which textbook is good to learn on Mathematics II. At least more than 1 textbook, or just textbook for each curriculum. I really need suggestion.

Comment: What an interesting edit...I imagine this question no longer really applies.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Edits like this really aren't helpful - the question is still low quality after the edit, and now also improperly tagged. It's better to leave such questions alone, since editing brings them more attention.